# gae sessions with django on GAE

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Please need some help on this. Following is my error traceback.I'm using gaesessions with django 1.2 on GAE. I'm getting following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 4053, in _HandleRequest
    self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3977, in _Dispatch
    base_env_dict=env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 588, in Dispatch
    base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3050, in Dispatch
    self._module_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2954, in ExecuteCGI
    reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2834, in ExecuteOrImportScript
    exec module_code in script_module.__dict__
  File "D:\projects\tutorial\selftutor.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\projects\tutorial\selftutor.py", line 35, in main
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\util.py", line 98, in run_wsgi_app
    run_bare_wsgi_app(add_wsgi_middleware(application))
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\util.py", line 116, in run_bare_wsgi_app
    result = application(env, _start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django_1_2\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 252, in __call__
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "D:\projects\tutorial\gaesessions\__init__.py", line 491, in process_response
    if request.session.is_accessed():
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'session'
```

On one link it is working. There is no error but on another above error is shown. When I debug the code using pycharm 'process_request' function of the 'DjangoSessionMiddleware' is never entered. I don'tknnow what is the problem. Please any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions#readme :

> If you want to gae-sessions with Django, add
>   'gaesessions.DjangoSessionMiddleware' to your list of
>   MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in your settings.py file. You can then access the
>   session associated with the current request via the request.session
>   variable. To configure the Django middleware, modify the following
>   line in gaesessions/__ init__.py:

```
self.wrapped_wsgi_middleware = SessionMiddleware(fake_app, cookie_key='you MUST change this')
```

Comment: I've already done that. I'm passing 64 bit key in cookie_key which I'm generating offline(not in the app).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this error quite a few times. The reason for this error is incorrect code indentation in `views.py`.